# unable to create Inbound shipment

Tags: netsuite

unable to do inbound shipment

```
{
   type: "error.SuiteScriptError",
   name: "SSS_INVALID_SUBLIST_OPERATION",
   message: "You have attempted an invalid sublist or line item operation. You are either trying to access a field on a non-existent line or you are trying to add or remove lines from a static sublist.",
   stack: [
      "anonymous(N/serverRecordService)",
      "inboundResults(/SuiteScripts/inboundResults.js:40)"
   ],
   cause: {
      type: "internal error",
      code: "SSS_INVALID_SUBLIST_OPERATION",
      details: "You have attempted an invalid sublist or line item operation. You are either trying to access a field on a non-existent line or you are trying to add or remove lines from a static sublist.",
      userEvent: null,
      stackTrace: [
         "anonymous(N/serverRecordService)",
         "inboundResults(/SuiteScripts/inboundResults.js:40)"
      ],
      notifyOff: false
   },
   id: "",
   notifyOff: false,
   userFacing: false
}

 var objRecord1 = record.load({
    type:"receiveinboundshipment", 
    id: 2,
     isDynamic:true
});

var receiveItemCount=objRecord1.getLineCount('receiveitems');





var lineNum = objRecord1.selectLine({
    sublistId: 'receiveitems',
    line: 2
});

objRecord1.setCurrentSublistValue({
    sublistId: 'receiveitems',
    fieldId: 'receiveitem',
    value:  true,
    ignoreFieldChange: true
});

objRecord1.setCurrentSublistValue({
    sublistId: 'receiveitems',
    fieldId: 'quantitytobereceived',
    value:  1,
    ignoreFieldChange: true
});


objRecord1.commitLine({
    sublistId: 'item'
});

var recordId3 = objRecord1.save({
    enableSourcing: true,
    ignoreMandatoryFields: true
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The record **receiveinboundshipment** it's accesible from the script and the fields **receiveitem** and **quantitytobereceived** are correct.

The only thing which is not correct is that you are doing commit on a sublist **item** instead of **receiveitems**.

```
objRecord1.commitLine({
    sublistId: 'receiveitems'
});
```

You should replace the sublist 'item' for 'receiveitems' and it should work.

Good luck,